# Black screen after i close the lid and reopen

Tags: 18.04, suspend

After I close the lid of the laptop it doesn't enter in suspend mode. This happened immediately after an update of Ubuntu 18.04. I use the setting suspends when the laptop lid is closed OFF until I find a solution.

Why it doesn't suspend mode work?

Comment: I did a new installation of ubuntu and the result is the same : suspend mode doesn't work. The login screen remains locked and i must press and hold the power button to restart the os.

Comment: with latest update for ubuntu 18.04.3 the suspend mode is working

Comment: same problem with Lubuntu, the screen is back after opening, I can see the processor light but the screen remains black.

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome desktop, there’s no option in Settings utility for configuring laptop lid close actions. And Gnome Tweaks only offer a switch to enable/disable ‘Suspend when the laptop lid is closed.

Follow the steps:

- Open Terminal
- Paste the following command in the Terminal
  `sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`
- Provide your system password if it asks.
- Now you need to find the line **#HandleLidSwitch=suspend** & uncomment it (Remove the # from the beginning).
- It will be like the below image:
  [image]
- Save and exit the file.
- Now restart the Systemd service using the following command: `systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`

That's it, This method will fix your issue.

Comment: Just followed these steps. Hope it works

Comment: it does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. So you may have switched to Nvidia graphics drivers. If that's the case, just switch back to Intel and restart.

[image: Nvidia X server settings]

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me, although I dont like this solution.